# LEFT JOIN simple no me muestra registros que requiero

Tags: mysql, join

Ya tengo tiempo realizando inner join, sin embargo es la primera vez que ocupo aguno de los otros join(left,right,full) y requería el left join. Al tratar de usarlo no me da la consulta que requiero.

Consulta SQL

```sql
SELECT vacantes.*,COUNT(solicitantes_vac.id_sol) as 'cantidad' 
FROM vacantes 
LEFT JOIN solicitantes_vac ON vacantes.id_vac = solicitantes_vac.id_va
```

de momento sólo las tablas para probar cuentan con los siguientes datos en sus tablas:

tabla vacantes..

```
id_vac | nom_vac | desc_vac  |
   1   |mecanico |titulo..   |
   2   |conductor|licencia...|
```

y solicitantes..

```
id_sol | nom_sol | tel_sol  |id_vac|
   1   | armando |1234567890|  1   |
   2   |  jorge  |1234567890|  1   |
```

y me este es el resultado actual

```
id_vac | nom_vac | desc_vac  |cantidad|
   1   |mecanico |titulo..   |   2    |
```

y la que requiero es:

```
id_vac | nom_vac | desc_vac  |cantidad|
   1   |mecanico |titulo..   |    2   |
   2   |conductor|licencia...|    0   |
```

Comment: Intenta un group by nom_vac

Comment: si de hecho me sirvio gracias, crees que e podrias decir porque esto... se me hizo un tanto curioso que con eso se arreglara.. si quieres haz la respuesta y te la marco como valida :D

Comment: Si amigo te hace falta un GROUP BY al no ponerlo MYSQL solo te devolvera un registro

Comment: Las funciones de agregación como count operan sobre un grupo de datos y devuelven una única fila, por eso necesitas agrupar para crear grupos de datos por alguna columna específica

Comment: @persona_A Con el COUNT te devuelve solo un registro, al hacerlo por un group by agrupas la consulta por regristro

Comment: a okey  gracias. ya me quedo claro :D

Comment: Responde tu propia pregunta, o si ves que no tiene sentido eliminala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade a la consulta SQL lo siguiente:

```sql
 group by nom_vac
```

debería quedar así..

```sql
SELECT vacantes.*,COUNT(solicitantes_vac.id_sol) as 'cantidad' FROM vacantes LEFT JOIN solicitantes_vac ON vacantes.id_vac = solicitantes_vac.id_va groyp by nom_vac
```

Las funciones de agregación como count operan sobre un grupo de datos y devuelven una única fila, por eso necesitas agrupar para crear grupos de datos por alguna columna específica
esto es debido a que las funciones como **COUNT** operan sobre grupos de datos en el caso que coloque solo manejaba el grupo de la función por lo que solo daba un resultado sin embargo al agruparlos por el nombre me daría el resultado querido que seria por consulta.

Nota: En mi caso resulto ser mejor agruparlos por el id o es decir usar:

```sql
 group by di_vac
```

dado que como podia llegar a tener un nombre igual pero una descripción diferente se mesclavan lo de 2 vacantes por lo que en este caso el id es único era mas factible